# Connecting Graylog to an already existing Elasticsearch - Cant see anything

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2, graylog

I've been working with Elasticsearch\Kibana for quite some time now but recently considered moving to Graylog. If I understand this correctly, I should be able to query all my current indices through Graylog just as with Kibana. The thing is I dont see anything under System -> Indices:

[image]

Do I need to re-create index sets much like Kibana's Index Patterns or is there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: In general, the official Graylog discussion forums are a better place to ask Graylog-related questions: https://community.graylog.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graylog expects full authority over its indices.

It's not possible to query arbitrary existing Elasticsearch indices with Graylog as it's expecting the documents to have a specific format.

You can query existing Elasticsearch indices created and populated by Graylog with Kibana, though.

For an explanation of the Graylog index model, please refer to http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.3/pages/configuration/index_model.html